# Delayed Jobs is not finding Records and failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, delayed-job

In my app, delayed jobs isn't running automatically on my server anymore. It used to..

When I manually ssh in, and perform rake jobs:work

I return this :

```
*** Starting job worker host:ip-(censored) pid:21458
* [Worker(host:ip-(censored) pid:21458)] acquired lock on PhotoJob
* [JOB] host:ip-(censored) pid:21458 failed with ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Photo with ID=9237 - 4 failed attempts
```

This returns roughly 20 times over for what I think is several jobs. Then I get a few of these:

```
* [Worker(host:ip-(censored) pid:21458)] failed to acquire exclusive lock for PhotoJob
```

And then finally one of these :

```
12 jobs processed at 73.6807 j/s, 12 failed ...
```

Any ideas what I should be mulling over? Thanks so much!

Edit :

Here is the photo controller that calls delayed jobs:

```
def update
   @gallery = @organization.media.find_by_media_id(params[:gallery_id]).media
   @photo = @gallery.photos.find(params[:id])

   if @photo.update_attributes(params[:photo])
      @photo.update_attribute(:processing, true)
      logger.info "HERE IS PROCESSING #{@photo.processing}"
      Delayed::Job.enqueue PhotoJob.new(@photo.id)
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html do 
            if params[:captions_screen] == 'true'
               logger.info "WE ARE GOING TO DO NOTHING AT ALL"
               render :text => ''
            else
               redirect_to organization_media_url(@organization) 
            end
         end
         format.js { redirect_to organization_media_url(@organization) }
      end
   else
      render :action => 'edit'
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many many thanks to Tadas Tamosauskas on helping out, but after some research, I found that the problem is actually with delayed_jobs. What happened was when I deployed to a cluster server, the server overwrote my recipes on my ey-cloud for delayed_jobs to initialize. So delayed jobs never booted up. The jobs never ran. Updated the recipe, redeployed, everything is hunky dory.

Answer (score 1):

Open your scripts/console and try to Photo.find(9237). You will probably get the same error. This means something/someone is calling controller action for unexistent record. You can avoid this by using find_by_id(params[:id]) which will return nil if there is no record with given id. Also add one more condition in your if statement

```
if @photo.present? && @photo.update_attributes(params[:photo])
```